# Method Patch isn't allowed in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, patch

I need to have an opportunity to handle Patch request, namely getting a person to update from an HTML form.

To do this, I declared this method that handles patch requests:

```
 @PatchMapping(path = "/person/update", consumes = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Person> updatePerson(@RequestBody Person person) {
        try {
            var updatedUser = service.update(person);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(updatedUser);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And here is the HTML form for updating Person:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Update user</title>
    <script src="/js/updateUserHandler.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <form method="post" action="/person/update" th:object="${person}" id="updateUser">
        <nobr>PERSON DATA</nobr>
        <input type="submit" name="save" value="save">
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" th:value="${person.getName()}">
        <br>
        <nobr>User name:</nobr>
        <input type="text" name="surname" th:value="${person.getSurname()}">
        <br>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I know I can't directly send data from an HTML form using the Patch method, so I override the default logic of sending form data with the Post method using the following JS:

```
window.addEventListener('load',
    () => {
        const myForm = document.getElementById('updateUser');
        myForm.addEventListener('submit',
            (event) => {
                event.preventDefault();
                const data = new FormData(myForm);

                const json = {};
                data.forEach((value, key) => json[key] = value);
                const jsonStr = JSON.stringify(json);

                const endpoint = `/person/update`;

                fetch(endpoint, { // THIS LINE THROWS AN ERROR THAT THE METHOD IS NOT ALLOWED
                    method: 'patch',
                    body: jsonStr,
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
                })            
          })
    })
```

So, the problem is that after doing all the above steps, I get this response:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-07-10T18:24:53.019+00:00",
    "status": 405,
    "error": "Method Not Allowed",
    "path": "/person/update"
}
```

At the same time, the server returns the correct response if I send a request by curl:

```
curl -X PATCH --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --data '{"name": "Vanes", "surname": "Kann", "age": "25"}' \
 http://localhost:8080/person/update
```

Comment: Have you tried "curl -X PATCH ...", just to make sure it isn't your JS code/browser?

Comment: Please read: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) --- "*`<form method="post" ....`*" - This part is executing a `POST`, not a `PATCH`.

Comment: @BillMair I tried it right now and I see that it's not a server problem, because the server responded correctly. Thank you, now I'll try to understand what the problem really is

Comment: @Turing85 thanks for your note about the screenshot! Yes, that part is executing a POST, but I use js for preventing the default logic, so requests are sent with PATCH. And it turned out that the problem is actually not in the server.